# performing self joins with fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

```
SELECT f1.uid1, f1.uid2
FROM friend AS f1
JOIN friend AS f2
    ON f1.uid1 = f2.uid1
        AND f2.uid2 = me()
JOIN friend AS f3
    ON f1.uid2 = f3.uid2
        AND f3.uid1 = me()
```

That query gets me the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected 'AS' at position 40.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 601
  }
}
```

Does FQL not support self joins? If it does how does it work if you can't alias tables with AS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FQL does not support JOIN. Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/ for available features.